# How to iterate over queryobject in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to iterate over Query-object to process and send response accordingly.

This is working JavaScript part

```
var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "jsonview/", async: false}).responseText;
document.write(msg);
```

This is working django views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def jsonview(request):
    return JsonResponse({"foo":"bar", "spam" : "no"})
```

I get the result `{"foo": "bar", "spam": "no"}`

but I want to do like this (Don't Ask why).

```
var msg = $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "jsonview/",
                    data:{["foo","spam"]},
                    async: false
                    }).responseText;
  document.write(msg);




def jsonview(request):
      spam_dict = {"foo":"bar", "spam" : "no"}
      new_dict = {}
      for item in request.GET.get('data'):
          new_dict[item] = spam_dict[item]
    return JsonResponse(new_dict)

desired -> {"foo":"bar", "spam" : "no"}
```

I tried various methods like

```
for item in request.GET:
for item in request.GET.get('data')
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `data` key in your request; that's just the parameter jQuery uses to pass the data value to the ajax function.

Also note that `{["foo","spam"]}` in JS evaluates to just `["foo","spam"]`; you can't have an object with no key, it is just an array.

Because this is not form-encoded data, you cannot use `request.GET` or `request.POST` in Python. You can read this data from `request.body`, but it would be better to pass it as JSON and parse it at the other end. So, in JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jsonview/",
    data: JSON.stringify(["foo","spam"]),
    ...
});
```

and in Python:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am on mobile. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

[request.GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) is a dictionary-like object and can be iterated over like any other Python dictionary:

```
>>> from django.http.request import HttpRequest
>>> req = HttpRequest()
>>> req.GET["test"] = 5
>>> req.GET["test2"] = "pouet"
>>> for key, val in req.GET.items():
...     print(key, val)
... 
test2 pouet
test 5
```

In few words, just use `for key, val in request.GET.items():` to iterate over your dict and get each key and value in `key` and `val` variables.

**additional notes:**

- `for item in request.GET:` just iterates over the keys of the dictionary
- `for item in request.GET.get('data'):` tries to iterate over a the value associated to the `'data'` key in the dict (which does not exist)
- `request.GET.items()` returns an iterator fetching each key/value pair in the form of a tuple. You could just retrieve the tuple by storing it in a single variable like this `for key_value_pair in request.GET.items():` and then access the key with `key_value_pair[0]` and the value with `key_value_pair[1]`. But it is much more convenient to map each value of the tuple in a variable with `for key, val in request.GET.items():`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that way. I may be missing something in javascript part

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var msg = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "jsonview/",
                    data: {"data": ["foo","spam"]},
                    async: false
                    }).responseText;
document.write(msg);
```

Then in view

```
for item in request.POST.getlist('data[]'):
```

Comment: I tried this. Doesn't seem to work. I will try. Thanks